# How to add commands at runtime, or to define behavior for unknown commands?

Tags: go, go-cobra

I have a project that works with *modules*, which are called with CLI commands (ie. `myapp foo` calls the `foo` module).

Modules can be builtin or user defined. I defined some builtin modules with Cobra commands and it works well. Now I want to handle user defined modules, so `myapp bar` will look for a `bar` file in some folder, since the `bar` command is not defined.

How to do this without having a `unknown command "bar"` error, or to add commands at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

It's possible to do this with [AddCommand](https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/cobra#Command.AddCommand).